# Best way to bind events (with dynamic data) to elements after ajax load in raw JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, dom-events

After html is entered into a container from a ajax response I would like to bind an event to various elements. I know this can be achieved by running `addEventListener` or `on+event=function(){}` right after the html is inserted.

My problem is that I am unsure of the best method to do so with dynamic content, whereas the data passed into the event is different each time.

For example, the following html is loaded into a container:

```
<button id="myButton">go</button>
```

Now, I need to bind an `onclick` function to the button element that contains data that was rendered on the remote side - the `onclick` function would be something like:

```
myFunction($data1,$data2,$data3);
```

whereas `$data1,$data2,$data3` are variables with the dynamic data.
One way I can have this function bound to the button is by outputting a script to be evaluated after the HTML data is inserted into the container, so the HTML output would go like this:

```
<button id="myButton">go</button>
<script>document.getElementById('myButton').addEventListener('click',function(){myFunction(<?php echo $data1.','.$data2.','.$data3 ?>)});})</script>
```

Is there anyway I can achieve the result from the above code in a more flexible way without having to output that script line for every element and for each request?

A way that I thought of is to have a bind function that is called after every request is completed, and in this function every element that needs an event bound is stored in an array. A loop goes through the array and binds the appropriate event and function - but this gets complicated with dynamic data. Any ideas?

Comment: why would you need to echo parameters into myFunction if you are doing an ajax call? Doesnt the response give you some form of data back?

Comment: The response gives me back HTML. The parameters were determined by the ajax call's response. So now I need to bind an event to an element in that HTML using data in the same response. (I am trying to avoid using inline events as well)

Comment: Can the button's ID be used to determine what values should be passed to myFunction()? So specifically what data1,data2,...etc will be?

Comment: Nope. The data is different every time for the same element so a unique ID would not help in this case. I accepted lan's solution below which involves using the data- attribute. This way I can store the dynamic data in the element itself and access it through a static function.

Comment: Yepp that seems like the the best you can get at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your own form of event delegation:

```
var container = document.getElementById("container");
container.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    if (target.tagName === "BUTTON") {
        // execute handler code for buttons
    }
}, false);
```

Where the `container` element is the closest, stable (not being added/removed from the DOM) element that these dynamic elements/buttons are being added to at some level.

The event is bound once to one containing element, but is triggered for any `click` event that bubbles up from descendants (the default behavior of `click` events).

This will simply check if the `tagName` of the element is "button". This is pretty broad, but if this is the thing you want to filter out, that's what you can use. If you want to use a `class`, add a specific `class` (maybe "special-class") to the dynamic buttons and use:

```
if (~(" " + target.className + " ").indexOf(" special-class ")) {
    // execute handler for buttons with class "special-class"
}
```

If you need to pass specific data with the buttons/elements, add a specific `data-*` attribute that contains it, to the buttons when generating them:

```
<button id="whateverId" data-data1="$data1" data-data2="$data2" data-data3="$data3">go</button>
```

And in the event handler where you know it's the targeted buttons, you can use:

```
var data1 = target.getAttribute("data-data1");
var data2 = target.getAttribute("data-data2");
var data3 = target.getAttribute("data-data3");
```

Reference:

- http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/all-you-need-to-know-about-the-html5-data-attribute/
- http://caniuse.com/dataset

Comment: How would I pass dynamic variables into the handler code for a specific button? This seems like it is only suitable if it is a static function that always has the same parameters.

Comment: @user969622 Just updated my answer (stuff at the end), so hopefully that helps.

Comment: Looks promising, but what if the browser does not support HTML5?

Comment: @user969622 From here ( http://caniuse.com/dataset ) - "**Note:** All browsers can already use data-* attributes and access them using getAttribute."